# Axios PUT request failed with 500 code Cast to ObjectId failed for value

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, axios

I'm new to MERN stack and I'm trying to make a put request with axios to change the user profile information but I'm getting the following error as a response : {"message":"Cast to ObjectId failed for value "profile" (type string) at path "_id" for model "User""}
Here is the entire project : https://github.com/burNN11/new-project

Comment: Can you provide your example request, and maybe `req.user` as well ?

Comment: Please check that the value of your `req.user._id` in your profile endpoint is a valid ObjectId string.

Comment: Hi, the problem is that I have http://localhost:3000/profile and profile is not a compatible mongoDB string, but I've seen a lot of people on youtube make it like this. This guy at 5:14:00 has the exactly code like mine and it's working for him : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CDtPMR5y0QU&t=19413s&ab_channel=CodingwithBasir . And I've seen other examples too. I don't know how to do it, why doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have the following in the router:

- `router.put('/:id')`
- `router.put('/profile')`

When you make a PUT request to `/profile`, express will invoke the first route (`/:id`), and treats `profile` as an id.

Solution: change your route name to PUT `/profile/:id`